# Awesome Window Manager and gnome-session

Tags: ubuntu, gnome3, awesome

I am running Ubuntu 14.10, on top of standard unity/gnome I have installed Awesome Window Manager using this tutorial:

http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-awesome-window-manager-3-5-6-on-ubuntu-14-10-ubuntu-14-04-and-derivative-systems/

Awesome works, however because it's not a standard Ubuntu any more some bits are not working, notably when picking display/monitor settings from unity-control-center there is a an error message like that:

GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon was not provided by any .service files

My guess is that gnome-session is not running or some services related to gnome are not auto-started correctly.

I cannot change display settings, I cannot change keyboard settings.

Please advice what to do.